# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass when submitting the selection tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. And now I have a question when submitted the form. 
When submitted the form, it will shows

```
NoMethodError in Foods#new, Showing ..../new.html.erb where line #16 raised:
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

while the line 16 is:

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Please select") %>
```

I am a little confused with the method map, do I need to add it into create action?

here is my new action

```
def new
@food = Food.new    
@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end
```

And here is my create action

```
def create
@food = Food.new(food_params)
@food.category_id = params[:category_id]

if @food.save
  flash[:success] = "Adding Successful!"
  redirect_to @food
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def food_params
params.require(:food).permit(:name, :price, :category_id, :description, :picture)
end
```

Would anyone could help me solve the problem?

Comment: Just to rule out the simple, do you have any categories in your db?

Comment: @categories is nil. That's your problem.You don't have any categories in your database.

Comment: yep, I have set categories in seeds.rb

Answer (score 1):

I see one issue in your create method.

In the event @food.save == false, you're not building

```
@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
```

before

```
render 'new'
```

So likely your form isn't getting the @categories info it needs to build the select statement.

Comment: @crystal, just add another `@categories = ...` before the `render :new`, just like he said

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have any categories in your database, a more safe method would be using `collection_select`, it should handle empty collections gracefully.

First here's the controller

```
def new
  @food = Food.new    
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Then the view

```
collection_select(:food, :category_id, @categories, :id, :name)
```

The other problem is the absense of the `@categories` in the creation action when the `@food` isn't saved, and that fails when the form is building the dropdown, If you want to simplify this you could add a method that prepares this

```
def prepare_form_data
  @categories = Category.all
end

def new
  @food = Food.new
  prepare_form_data
end
def create
  @food = Food.new(food_params)
  if @food.save
    # do stuff
  else
    prepare_form_data # prepare the data for the second form
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `render 'new'`, it copies over instance variables into that ERB rendering. In your new action you make an instance variable `@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }` and then reference it. You need to define that in the create action as well in the else. Preferably with a shared method.

As in:

```
before_action ->{ @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] } }, only: %i[new create]

def new
  @food = Food.new
end

def create
  @food = Food.new(food_params)
  @food.category_id = params[:category_id]

  if @food.save
    flash[:success] = 'Adding successful!'
    redirect_to @food
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: it might works as there is no error but it could not redirect to @food, the show page

Comment: def show
    @food = Food.find(params[:id])
    end

Comment: I have set a category validation before and I forget to change it  --